# How to convert RDF to string

Tags: java, rdf, jena

I create some RDF file wih JENA library: `Model model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();`...
now how I can I convert this to string ?

thx

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
String syntax = "RDF/XML-ABBREV"; // also try "N-TRIPLE" and "TURTLE"
StringWriter out = new StringWriter();
model.write(out, syntax);
String result = out.toString();
```

This uses Jena's built-in writers that can already output RDF graphs in the various supported RDF syntaxes, such as RDF/XML and Turtle and N-Triples. If you just want to dump to `System.out`, then it's even easier:

```
model.write(System.out, "RDF/XML-ABBREV");
```

Answer (score 0):

A RDF model is a set of **Statements**. Every time you add a property to the model, a Statement is created...and a Statement in RDF model is also called as a '**Triple**', coz it has 3 parts: Subject (Resource), Predicate (Property) and Object (RDFNode - can be a Resource). You can call the toString method on these objects, as shown in the code below:

```
// list the statements in the Model
StmtIterator iter = model.listStatements();

// print out the predicate, subject and object of each statement
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    Statement stmt      = iter.nextStatement();  // get next statement
    Resource  subject   = stmt.getSubject();     // get the subject
    Property  predicate = stmt.getPredicate();   // get the predicate
    RDFNode   object    = stmt.getObject();      // get the object

    System.out.print(subject.toString());
    System.out.print(" " + predicate.toString() + " ");
    if (object instanceof Resource) {
       System.out.print(object.toString());
    } else {
        // object is a literal
        System.out.print(" \"" + object.toString() + "\"");
    }

    System.out.println(" .");
}
```

Note the 'toString' method in the above code.

Source/Ref: [Jena - RDF](http://incubator.apache.org/jena/tutorials/rdf_api.html) (Check the 'Statements' section).

Comment: rdf is a xml and xml is some string so some toString method will be usefull. Btw can you explain me different between Resource and literal ?

Comment: This is not an appropriate way to serialize a model to RDF.  As cygri shows, model's can write themselves to output streams/writers in any supported RDF syntax, do not do it by hand.

Comment: That code is from the JENA framework's documentation. The above post has a reference, where you can check that.

Comment: Well, it's an example from a tutorial that shows how to use the Jena API. I agree with @Michael that this isn't something you should ever do by hand – you can do the same in one line using `model.write()`.